# Volley disable cache for one request

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

I want to use the default cache policy of volley for all my requests **except one**. Is this possible?

I would like to get the response from internet every time this request is called.

Thank's in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily disable cache for a particular request by changing the method   `com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(NetworkResponse response)` and ignore these headers, set `entry.softTtl` and `entry.ttl` fields to whatever value works for you and use your method in your request class. Here is an example:

```
 public static Cache.Entry parseIgnoreCacheHeaders(NetworkResponse response) {

long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

Map<String, String> headers = response.headers;
long serverDate = 0;
String serverEtag = null;
String headerValue;

headerValue = headers.get("Date");
if (headerValue != null) {
    serverDate = HttpHeaderParser.parseDateAsEpoch(headerValue);
}

serverEtag = headers.get("ETag");

final long cacheHitButRefreshed = 3 * 60 * 1000; // in 3 minutes cache will be hit, but also refreshed on background
final long cacheExpired = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // in 24 hours this cache entry expires completely
final long softExpire = now + cacheHitButRefreshed;
final long ttl = now + cacheExpired;

Cache.Entry entry = new Cache.Entry();
entry.data = response.data;
entry.etag = serverEtag;
entry.softTtl = softExpire;
entry.ttl = ttl;
entry.serverDate = serverDate;
entry.responseHeaders = headers;

return entry;
 }
```

Use this method in you response like this

```
public class MyRequest extends com.android.volley.Request<MyResponse> {

...

@Override
protected Response<MyResponse> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    String jsonString = new String(response.data);
    MyResponse MyResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyResponse.class);
    return Response.success(MyResponse, HttpHeaderParser.parseIgnoreCacheHeaders(response));
}

}
```

Answer (score 10):

This would work:

```
request.setShouldCache(false);
```